# Can't make a private method in C++ return a pointer to a private nested class

Tags: c++

This one doesn't want to compile:

```
class MainClass
{
public:
    ...

private:
    class NestedClass
    { //Line 39
        ...
    };

    class NestedClass * getNestedClassFor(int i);
};
```

The compiler says:

> error: 'class MainClass::NestedClass' is private

However, if I made NestedClass `public`, it would work.

Why doesn't it work? It's not as though I'm exporting a nested class through a public method? It's just a private method returning a pointer to a private class. Any ideas?

Thanks!

### Update

Fixed the semi-columns. They're not the problem. Neither is writing `class` in front of NestedClass.

Here's the error message:

> MainClass.h: In function 'MainClass::NestedClass* getNestedClassFor(int i)':
>
> MainClass.h:39: error: 'class MainClass::NestedClass' is private
>
> MainClass.cpp:49: error: within this context

Here's the part of the .cpp file that's also complaining:

```
class MainClass::NestedClass * getNestedClassFor(int i) //Line 49
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Are there more errors that might be related?

Comment: You're missing semicolons after the class definitions.

Comment: Is this the actual code? There are two missing semi-colons.

Comment: Why do you put `class` infront of `getNestedClassFor`?

Comment: It should work if you put the definition of `getNestedClassFor` in the header. Is your problem with the declaration or the definition?

Comment: @YankoYankov: It doesn't matter where you put it; the compiler doesn't see headers (the preprocessor inserts them into the .cpp file).

Comment: @MSalters: I was thinking he might be doing something wrong in the definition (as it seems he was).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had forgotten to add the class scope in the .cpp, i.e.

```
class MainClass::NestedClass * getNestedClassFor(int i)
{
   //...
}
```

Should be

```
class MainClass::NestedClass * MainClass::getNestedClassFor(int i)
{
   //...
}
```

***Stupid me!***

Answer (score 3):

This compiles and works fine:

```
class A {
private:
    class B {
    public:
        B() {};
    };

    B *b;   
    B *getB();

public:
    A();
};

A::A()
{
    b = getB();
}

A::B* A::getB()
{
    A::B *tmp = new A::B();
    return tmp;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

one error is: *(In fact it is not a error, just a stylish, see comments bellow)*

```
class NestedClass * getNestedClassFor(int i);
```

should be only:

```
 NestedClass * getNestedClassFor(int i);
```

Another is: when you declare a nested class, you should finish the declaration with a ";"

```
private:
  class NestedClass
  {
      ...
  };
```

May be there has another errors there...

Comment: The first (redundant `class`) is not an error, but merely C style.

Comment: The first "error" isn't one---it's not very C++ish, but using `class` or `struct` here is legal C++.  (For reasons of C compatibility: C requires `struct` here, and since `class` and `struct` are basically the same thing...)  The missing semicolon is an error, although the error message is really weird for it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do it? You shouldn't expose private stuff to outside clients. That's the whole point of encapsulation. Make it public if it's needed to be accessible from outside.

Comment: Or make it **opaque** (like a `HANDLE`).

Comment: It's about hiding an implementation stuff. Sometimes you need some data structures to calculate something and you don't want to expose this API so that you can change the implementation later without changing the API.

Answer (score 0):

> Why doesn't it work? It's not as though I'm exporting a nested class through a public method? It's just a private method returning a pointer to a private class. Any ideas?

The compiler message is very clear. You're returning a pointer to a private nested class. The called of this function would then need to know the structure of this class, however since the class is private, then getting the structure is prohibited. You should private some of the class' attributes and methods, not the class itself. Even so, if you make all attributes and methods private then this class would have no use case.

What are you trying to achieve anyway?

Comment: But the function is private. Why not pass a private inner object to another private function?